# TargetFolderName with space character (char)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-templates

I'm using visual studio templates in order to build a custom visual studio template project. I'm trying to create a folder with a name «External Models» that has space char but the visual studio is creating a folder with the name «External%20Models» replacing the space by %20.

Follows my .vstemplate file:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">

<TemplateData>
   ...
</TemplateData>

<TemplateContent>

  <Project TargetFileName="Product.Models.csproj" File="Product.Models.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">

    ...

    <Folder Name="GeneratedCode" TargetFolderName="GeneratedCode">
        ...
    </Folder>
    <Folder Name="External Models" TargetFolderName="External Models">
      <Folder Name="CorePatterns" TargetFolderName="CorePatterns">
        ...
      </Folder>
    </Folder>
  </Project>
</TemplateContent>

<WizardExtension>
    ...
</WizardExtension>
```

And the content of the .vsix files generated:

[image: ual]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed from this:

```
<Folder Name="External Models" TargetFolderName="External Models">
  <Folder Name="CorePatterns" TargetFolderName="CorePatterns">
        ...
  </Folder>
</Folder>
```

To this, and start to work.

```
<Folder Name="ExternalModels" TargetFolderName="External Models">
  <Folder Name="CorePatterns" TargetFolderName="CorePatterns">
        ...
  </Folder>
</Folder>
```

**Explanation:**

It does not matter which folders are generated to create the .vsix installer. What is matter is `TargetFolderName="External Models"` tag name which will generate the project folder (during the Visual Studio->File->Create new project). By changing the `Name="External Models"` to `Name="ExternalModels"` and, in the template project that generate the .vsix, change the name of the folder "External Models" to "ExternalModels" everithing will work fine.